# how to invalidate the input if it contains white space?

Tags: javascript, node.js

so i have this input for user name

```
 <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="form-control"value="{{username}}">
```

i have a validation where it will invalidate the input if it contains special characters with this `var regex = /^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/;`

```
if (regex.test(uname) === false) {
      printError("usernameErr", "Please enter a valid name");
      return false;
```

but how can i invalidate the input if it contains white space? please help thank you

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/bS6ht0/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current RegEx matches all lowercase (`[a-z]`), uppercase (`[A-Z]`) alphabets and space (`\s`) character.

Simply removing the space (`\s`) matching character form the RegEx should work:

```
var regex = /^[a-zA-Z]+$/;
```